# Node.js read request body from Fetch API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following method on my frontend:

```
price.addEventListener("click", function() {
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/payment", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      amount: {
        currency: "EUR",
        amount: "10.00"
      },
      description: "Description of the item to buy"
    })
  })
});
```

and the following is my Node.js server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.listen(3000);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
  next();
});

app.post("/payment", function (req, res) {
  // console.log(req.body);
  // console.log(req.method);
  // console.log(req.headers);
  client.payments.create({
    amount: {
      value: req.body.amount.amount,
      currency: req.body.amount.currency
    },
    description: req.body.description,
  })
    .then(payment => {
      // Forward the customer to the payment.getCheckoutUrl()
      res.redirect(payment.getCheckoutUrl());
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // Handle the error
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

I do not get why my `req.body` returns `undefined` and I cannot access those values. When I click to buy an item from UI, in the console I get `POST 500 (Internal Server Error)` and it may be intuitive that this does not work and this might explain this. But I can see that `req.method` and `req.headers` have values and it seems they are working properly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to add `body-parser` so that it will convert the request in the desired format

Comment: You need a middleware to parse request body. You can use `body-parser` package or the one provided by express --> `app.use(express.json());`. Make sure that this line of code is before any request handling code. For details, see [express](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express)